# Как читать и изменять файл БД на сайте с помощью Python-модуля?

Tags: android, база-данных, kivy, sqlite3

Пишу приложение под Android на фреймворке Kivy ([www.kivy.org](http://www.kivy.org)). Также есть веб-страница с файлом БД SQLite (код работает с ним с помощью sqlite3). Программа должна иметь возможность просматривать и обновлять файл на сайте. Какой модуль Питона для этого годится и если такого модуля нет, то как это реализовать? Пробовал Requests, но там нет обновления и закидывания на сайт нового файла.

Comment: Никак. Переходите на MySQL или подобные БД. SQlite для этого не годится.

Comment: Второй вариант: делать API на PHP или Python на сервере. Который будет изменять нужные данные в базе по HTTP запросу из приложения. Но это уже костыли.